# For how long does a session last by default?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

For how long does a *session* :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

last when I do not explicitly declare `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(int i)`? Let us assume, the user doesn't delete the cookies from his browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the declared value of `session-timeout` in `web.xml` states. If there is no value specified there, the container decides this setting.

Comment: every server might be having different value ? And is it dependent upon the user deleting the cookies ?\

Comment: Cookies are used for tracking the session. If the user deletes the cookie, the session will be terminated. The `session-timeout` value determines the `Max-Age` setting of the cookie. And yes, every type of server (e.g., Tomcat, WebSphere, JBoss...) will have its own default setting. This setting will be usually `30 minutes`.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpSession` has `getMaxInactiveInterval` method which can tell you how much the session will stay available for the user.

If you `setMaxInactiveInterval` to a negative number it'll never expire as long as he doesn't delete cookies.

**EDIT :** For your commentary on the other answer where I can't add a comment, if the user doesn't accept cookies, he'll never have a session. So if he deletes it, he'll start a new session.